# React/react-router redirect to a set of URLs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

The use case is, my users might upload a set of photos, each needs to be associated with a set of meta info the user will fill in. So after upload the set of files, I'd like to redirect the user to first photo's meta editor page, and then when he click the "next" button, he goes to the second.

I'm wondering how shall I implement this using react and react-router?

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I had taken. Upload all the pictures to the server first and create a new album or a temporary data structure which stores the image id of all the uploaded pics. Then redirect to a new url with the album id. Ex - redirect to `<domain.com>/album/:id`

When you enter this URL (album/:id), query for the list of images and iterate over the images. Url would look like `<domain.com>/album/:id/photo/photo_id`

Even facebook does something similar.

Comment: would storing them in redux store be easier?

Comment: One advantage of uploading the pictures to the server first is that you can reuse the template to perform CRUD operations on the photo because the url `<domain.com>/album/:id/photo/photo_id/edit` will be consistent (photo id will be created in the database). This will ensure that your URL is deep linked and also the navigation buttons on the browser works correctly. I like this approach since it follows RESTful architecture. I can't think of doing the same using redux store i.e upload the photos and the metadata at one go. History is not preserved in this case. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Definitely! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the newer [react-router v4](https://react-router.now.sh/basic) you could easily setup a redirect in your `render()` method like so

```
  render() {
    const { uploadsCompleted } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        {uploadsCompleted && (
          <Redirect to={`/uploads/1`}/>
        )}
        <div>
          {/* Your upload progress info goes in here and is only displayed when the uploads are still in progress. */}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

To handle the file uploads and track the upload progress you could use [react-fileupload](https://github.com/SoAanyip/React-FileUpload) which allows you to hook into the `uploadSuccess` or `uploading` events so that you can track the progress and issue a `setState` to set the `uploadsCompleted` state key to `true`, thus forcing a redirect to the first image when the uploads are completed, provided that you did set up your routes `Match` correctly.